# generate address for wallet and create sub account

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, wallets, smart-contract-wallets

In bitcoin node we first create a wallet then generate address for it.
When you check balance you see sum balance all of them because all of them are in one wallet and you can withdrawal all balance with a single transaction.
What can i do this with Ethereum node???
I need a sub account!

Comment: Can you edit your question is specify what do you want to do exactly. Do you want a wallet in a browser? A phone? To interact with a Dapp programatically?

Comment: I want to use it for a exchange. I want to generate uniqe address for users. I did it. But I want to have a primary address and when any user withdrawal to own address, amount access in primary address so all balance aggregation on primary address same as btc node.